# Attempting to make an 'IMAGE' Embed code responsive in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have an embed code for an single image taken from a host picture archive. I want to attach the embed to my website so no one can drag the picture off and steal it.

The problem is it needs to be responsive to height and width and the set values in the embed are making it very difficult.

I have changed the width to 100% but obviously it makes the height non responsive - height is currently set at 1000. I can manually change them but it does not comply across all devices.

I need the image to shrink to the bloody device I am using it on and be responsive If i make my browser smaller or larger

Here is the embed code I have been putting into my CSS on Wordpress:

```
<iframe id="embed-frame-11855" style="border: 0px none;" src="(URL)" width="686" height="1000" scrolling="no" data-image-link="(URL)"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please don't shout at us – be patient and constructive, and we'll be more likely to help out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can improve your question by formatting your code for readability and to eliminate scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the picture stolen, putting it into an iframe won't prevent that. The source of the iframe can be opened in a new window (or tab) with the picture.

With that said, the general idea that you want is here:

http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/

You put your iframe into a containing div with the appropriate padding on the bottom and set the width and height to 100% of the containing div. Remember that your padding is your height as a percentage of width. So if you're embedding 4:3 images, for example, your padding-bottom would be 3/4, or 75%.